# Why does my flask template only expand one of its includes?

Tags: python, windows, flask

I am busy with a lesson in a Python course, meaning I'm quite the novice here, and have the following lines of flask template markup:

```
<div id="message">
    {{ error_message | safe }}
</div>
<div id="data">
    {% include geo_data ignore missing %}
</div>
<div id="download">
    {% include dl_button ignore missing %}
</div>
```

When I render the template with:

```
html = dataframe.to_html()
outfile = open("geocoded.html", "w")
outfile.write(html)
outfile.close()

return render_template("index.html", geo_data="geocoded.html", dl_button="download.html")
```

The template renders, but only includes `download.html` and not `geocoded.html`. I have checked the `geocoded.html` file and it contains a well-formed HTML table of the dataframe.

Why does the `dl_button` include render `download.html` but the `geo_data` include does not render `geocoded.html`?

Comment: Is `geocoded.html` in the same directory as `download.html`?  What are the permissions on both files?

Comment: @JohnGordon Aha, thank you, `geocoded.html` is not in my `templates` folder.

Comment: @JohnGordon Why not answer and I'll accept, thanks, your comment helped me solve the problem.